# How to pass decimal values over serialport in C#?

Tags: c#

how to pass decimal values over serialport control?

Answer (score 2):

Start by convering whatever values that you want to pass into a byte array ([`System.Byte()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte.aspx)), and then use the [`SerialPort.Write(Byte(), Int32, Int32)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551.aspx) to write them to the serial port.

That overload allows you to specify the array of bytes that will be passed, the offset of the array at which to begin, and the number of bytes out of the array that should be passed.

Obviously you've looked already, so you know that you are not going to find an overload for the [`SerialPort.Write` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.write.aspx) that writes integer or decimal values directly.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) Class.

Comment: thank u for that.. i want to pass 7 decimal values to serialport controll.. how to use serialport.write() method to pass intiger value??

Comment: Not sure how your serial port accepts incoming values, but you have to send everything as bytes, char or string. Under the hood, all values are sent as bytes anyway. Most likely, you would be sending the byte equivalent of your decimal numbers. From my experience, we usually convert these decimal numbers to whole numbers and then send them as series of bytes. But it all depends on how the device at the other end is configured.

Comment: can u please gve me the code for converting decimal to byte if the values are lyk 3,100,120,0,1,4??

Comment: byte[] bt = new byte[] { integer1, integer2, integer3,integer4, integer5, integer6 }; serialPort1.Write(bt, 0, 1); serialPort1.Write(bt, 1, 1); serialPort1.Write(bt, 2, 1); serialPort1.Write(bt, 3, 1); serialPort1.Write(bt, 4, 1); serialPort1.Write(bt, 5, 1);